# UWP Type Converter for Binding TextBlock values not processed on my XAML at design-time

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, typeconverter

I'm using a Type Converter to do some string manipulations on text being bound to TextBlocks in a UWP app.   I used a type converter class that I have used in a number of UWP apps with no issues.  But in a new UWP app I keep seeing the issue where the Binding value gets passed back and no changes have been made in the type converter to my passed values.  I had been using a type converter that takes parameters to take custom actions and that isn't working as well as a simple new type converter I created.  The odd thing is that the type converters work at run-time but as ignored at design-time.
Here are the parts of my code and XAML:

This is a data class that creates sample data for this repro to use for my bindings:

```
public class Alerts_DataClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string severity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastEventTime { get; set; }
}


public class AlertsSampleData : Alerts_DataClass
{
    public AlertsSampleData()
    {

        Alerts_DataClass myAlert = new Alerts_DataClass { id = "636531490526731751_2124891065", title = "Category Type XVI", severity = "Medium", lastEventTime = new DateTime(2018, 2, 02) };

        this.id = myAlert.id;
        this.status = myAlert.status;
        this.title = myAlert.title;
        this.lastEventTime = myAlert.lastEventTime;
        this.severity = myAlert.severity;

    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="NestedBindingsTester.TypeConverterTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NestedBindingsTester"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="using:System"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <local:StringFormatConverterWithChangeType x:Key="StringFormatConverter"/>
        <local:DebugDataBindingConverter x:Key="DebugBinding"/>
        <local:ValueToStringConverter x:Key="valueToStringConverter" />
        <local:AlertsSampleData x:Key="data2"/>

    </Page.Resources>


    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="103*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="897*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" d:DataContext="{StaticResource data2}">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title, ConverterParameter=lower, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Margin="50,0,0,0"  />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title, Converter={StaticResource valueToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Margin="50,0,0,0" />

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And finally here are the two Type Converter modules.  The first is the simple one, valueToStringConverter which I just have take any String text passed and return it as lower case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace NestedBindingsTester
{

    public sealed class ValueToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {

            //return value?.ToString();
            string strThisTest = value.ToString().ToLower();
            return strThisTest;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Converting from string is not supported.");
        }
    }

}
```

And the original type converter I was using that takes parameters as switches for various actions called StringFormatConverter.  In my XAML example I am passing the parameter of 'lower' to tell it to convert the string value to lowercase:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;


namespace NestedBindingsTester
{

    public class DebugDataBindingConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            return "This is";
            ////return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            return "it";
            ////return value;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            ////throw new NotImplementedException();
            return "Hello moto";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sample usage:
    /// Text="{Binding Budget, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverterWithChangeType}, ConverterParameter='\{0:C2\}'}"
    /// </summary>
    public class StringFormatConverterWithChangeType : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members


        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            //  Used in UWP app
            //
            if (value != null)
            {
                // Arbitrarily remove dollar sign.
                //value = value.ToString().Replace("$", "");
            }
            else
            {
                value = "**NULL**";
            }

            if (parameter != null)
            {
                string formatString = parameter.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
                {
                    string strValue = value.ToString();
                    if (strValue != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
                    {
                        switch (formatString)
                        {
                            case "%":           // Add %
                                return String.Format("{0}%", value);
                            case "mi":          // Add miles
                                return String.Format("{0} miles", value);
                            case "caps":        // Convert to Initial caps
                                return UpperCaseFirstCharacter(value.ToString());
                            case "lower":        // Convert to Initial caps
                                return value.ToString().ToLower();
                            case "LiGa":        // Convert from Liters to Gallons
                                {
                                    //
                                    // Convert kilometers to miles.
                                    //  1 liter = 0.264172052 US gallons
                                    //
                                    double lConversion = 0.264172052;
                                    double liters = System.Convert.ToDouble(strValue);
                                    double gallons = lConversion * liters;
                                    return String.Format("{0:N1} gallons", gallons);
                                }
                            case "TimeMath":      // Compute time remaining until fully charged
                                {
                                    int Minutes = System.Convert.ToInt16(value);

                                    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                                    TimeSpan twoAndAHalfHours = new TimeSpan(0, Minutes, 0);
                                    DateTime estimatedFullChargedTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Minutes);
                                    string formattedTime = estimatedFullChargedTime.ToString("HH:mm");

                                    return formattedTime;
                                }
                            case "UTCtoShortDate":  // 02/03.2018
                                {
                                    string utcDate = value.ToString();            // "2018-01-26T02:17:23.5099802Z";
                                    DateTime dateTime;

                                    DateTime.TryParse(utcDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dateTime);
                                    Debug.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString());
                                    string strWDATP_Date = String.Format("{0:MM.dd.yyyy}", dateTime);
                                    return strWDATP_Date;
                                }
                            case "{0:d}":  // Short date.
                            case "{0:D}":   // Long date.
                                ////return String.Format(culture, formatString, System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(DateTime), null));
                                return String.Format("US", formatString, System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(DateTime), null));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return String.Format("US", formatString, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            return value.ToString();


        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                // Arbitrarily remove dollar sign.
                //value = value.ToString().Replace("$", "");
            }

            if (parameter != null)
            {
                string formatString = parameter.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
                {
                    string strValue = value.ToString();
                    if (strValue != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
                    {
                        switch (formatString)
                        {
                            case "%":           // Add %
                                return String.Format("{0}%", value);
                            case "mi":          // Add miles
                                return String.Format("{0} miles", value);
                            case "caps":        // Convert to Initial caps
                                return UpperCaseFirstCharacter(value.ToString());
                            case "LiGa":        // Convert from Liters to Gallons
                                {
                                    //
                                    // Convert kilometers to miles.
                                    //  1 liter = 0.264172052 US gallons
                                    //
                                    double lConversion = 0.264172052;
                                    double liters = System.Convert.ToDouble(strValue);
                                    double gallons = lConversion * liters;
                                    return String.Format("{0:N1} gallons", gallons);
                                }
                            case "TimeMath":      // Compute time remaining until fully charged
                                {
                                    int Minutes = System.Convert.ToInt16(value);

                                    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                                    TimeSpan twoAndAHalfHours = new TimeSpan(0, Minutes, 0);
                                    DateTime estimatedFullChargedTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Minutes);
                                    string formattedTime = estimatedFullChargedTime.ToString("HH:mm");

                                    return formattedTime;
                                }
                            case "{0:d}":  // Short date.
                            case "{0:D}":   // Long date.
                                return String.Format(culture, formatString, System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(DateTime), null));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return String.Format(culture, formatString, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }


        public string UpperCaseFirstCharacter(string text)
        {
            //return Regex.Replace(text, "^[a-z]", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
            return text.First().ToString().ToUpper() + text.Remove(0, 1).ToLower();
        }


        #endregion
    };



}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and targeting the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK (16299).

I just can't spot why it's no longer working as these type converters have been working fine in two other UWP projects.

NOTE:  I am using Binding in my binding for the TextBlocks since x:Bind does not work with design-time data.

Thanks for taking a look, I have been staring at this code for a while and can't find the problem.

Rick

Comment: If you make your target project to 15063, does this issue occur?

Comment: I can try that at some point but that's going really far back in SDKs as I am on Windows 10 1709 now and didn't want to target that far back as I am leveraging new UWP platform APIs.